# Arrange components in Javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm having trouble arranging the components in the group,
I'm trying to make this mybutton and mytextarea and my textfield components on the left.

It works with three of these components but when you put a fourth component in a single line all the components turn to the right. Sorry if English is bad,

```
setTranslateX (x);
setTranslateY (y);
```

Do not give me accurate results,
setLayoutx,y I think it does not work,
this my code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import tender.schedule.tm.Control.MyButton;
import tender.schedule.tm.Control.MyTabed;
import tender.schedule.tm.Control.MyTextArea;
import tender.schedule.tm.Control.MyTextField;

public class TenderScheduleTM extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group Tender = new Group();
    ObservableList ob = Tender.getChildren();

                                 //x      y
    MyTextArea mta =new MyTextArea(880, 110,300,100,"المادة");
    ob.add(mta);
    //mta.setLayoutX(800);
    //mta.setLayoutY(10);
                                     //x    y
    MyTextField mtf1 =new MyTextField(880, 230, 300, 40,"العدد");
    ob.add(mtf1);
    //mtf1.setLayoutX(890);
    //mtf1.setLayoutY(10);
                                     //x    y
    MyTextField mtf2 =new MyTextField(880, 280, 300, 40, "السعر");
    ob.add(mtf2);
    //mtf2.setLayoutX(890);
    //mtf2.setLayoutY(10);

    Image listimg=new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/list.png"));
                             //x    y
    MyButton mb1=new MyButton(1150, 0, 30, 30, new ImageView(listimg));
    //mb1.setLayoutX(1200);
    //mb1.setLayoutY(80);
    ob.add(mb1);

    MyTabed mb =new MyTabed();
    Tab t1 =new Tab();

    t1.setContent(Tender);
    mb.addTab("الجدول", t1);
    mb.addTab("المخطط", new Tab());

    Scene scene = new Scene(mb,1200,600);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tender Schedule");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Get this
[image: Get this]

any ideas? I would be grateful.

Comment: A `Group` takes on the union of the bounds of its child nodes, so the group itself is just going to be positioned regardless of the layout coordinates of the nodes it contains. Positioning everything "by hand" like this is usually a bad idea. You should use a specific [layout pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) (or combination of them) that provides the layout you want (something like a `VBox` with appropriate `alignment` settings and `spacing` should be enough here).

Comment: Don't try to manually set your `Nodes`. Use the `Layout` `Nodes` appropriately to get the result you want. You should start with maybe `BorderPane` or `HBox`. Just guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to achieve this layout style. Tab1 shows an example using `BorderPane`. Tab2 shows an example using `HBox`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingGrounds extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        //Example using BorderPane
        TextField textField1 = new TextField("textfield 1");
        TextArea textArea1 = new TextArea("textArea 1");
        TextArea textArea1b = new TextArea("TextArea 1b");
        Button btn1 = new Button("btn 1");
        VBox vBoxLeftRootTab1 = new VBox(textField1, textArea1, textArea1b, btn1);
        BorderPane borderPaneTab1Root = new BorderPane();
        borderPaneTab1Root.setLeft(vBoxLeftRootTab1);
        //You should probably set the Center and/or Right Node of the BorderPane
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("tab1");
        tab1.setContent(borderPaneTab1Root);

        //Example using HBox
        TextField textField2 = new TextField("textfield 2");
        TextArea textArea2 = new TextArea("textArea 2");
        TextArea textArea2b = new TextArea("TextArea 2b");
        Button btn2 = new Button("btn 2");
        VBox vBoxLeftRootTab2 = new VBox(textField2, textArea2, textArea2b, btn2);        
        //You may want to add more another layout Node in the HBox that will be to the right of what's on the left. 
        HBox hBoxTab2Root = new HBox(vBoxLeftRootTab2);
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("tab2");
        tab2.setContent(hBoxTab2Root);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1, tab2);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(tabPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 750, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```